# Prism app shuts down when exception during region creation

Tags: wpf, prism

We have an application that throws an UpdateRegionsException while launching. We suspect it has to do with a DataContext not being set properly in our XAML. Has anyone come across this type of problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there's a bug with elements such as Checkbox, and DatePicker, and perhaps others. On some cases I'm forced to put the DataContext prefix to my property name. For example,

```
IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.TransferOriginalRxInformationNeverFilled, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}"
```

If I don't put the DataContext prefix to the binding, the application shuts down during startup giving the following exception:

Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.UpdateRegionsException: An exception occurred while trying to create region objects.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.